# SAS univariate in R

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I am kind of new to stats and R and was hoping to find the equivalent of lognormal distribution of the proc univariate in SAS for R. The code is something like this,

```
Proc univariate data = dat;
histogram kilo / lognormal (theta=est zeta=est sigma=est noprint) 

      Midpoints 1 to 55477 by 20
Outhistogram=this;
Run;
```

Here the input data is dat and the variable chosen for the probability distribution is kilo. The value 55477 is the maximum value of the kilo variable.

The options for theta, zeta and sigma denote maximum estimated likelihood

I get the following after running the code. A table, with the following columns with 1 to 55477 by 20 (2774 records)(column explanation from sas website):

> *EXPPCT*  -  estimated percent of population in histogram interval determined from optional fitted distribution (here it is lognormal)
>
> *OBSPCT*  -  percent of variable values in histogram interval
>
> *VAR*   -  variable name (here it is kilo)
>
> *MIDPT*  -  midpoint of histogram interval

I am using the exppct, midpt values for further analysis.

Comment: plnorm() and dlnorm() fuctions can be used for model fitting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
## Sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- rlnorm(1000, 7)

## MLE estimates
library(fitdistrplus)
pars <- coef(fitdist(dat, "lnorm"))

## table variables
breaks <- seq(1, max(dat)+100, 100)                  # histogram breaks
mids <- diff(breaks)/2 + head(breaks, -1)            # midpoints
probs <- diff(plnorm(breaks, pars[[1]], pars[[2]]))  # expected probs for each bin
obs <- table(cut(dat, breaks)) / length(dat)         # observed 

res <- data.frame(MIDPT=mids,
                  OBSPCT=as.numeric(obs)*100,
                  EXPPCT=probs*100,
                  INTERVAL=names(obs))
head(res)
#   MIDPT OBSPCT    EXPPCT  INTERVAL
# 1    51    0.5 0.8775098   (1,101]
# 2   151    3.5 3.7212573 (101,201]
# 3   251    5.9 5.4240329 (201,301]
# 4   351    6.4 6.0203732 (301,401]
# 5   451    6.8 6.0371393 (401,501]
# 6   551    5.5 5.7785383 (501,601]

## Plot
hist(dat, breaks=breaks, freq=F, col="steelblue")
points((ps <- seq(1, max(dat)+100, len=1000)),
       dlnorm(ps, pars[[1]], pars[[2]]), type="l", col="salmon", lwd=3)
legend("topright", "Expected", col="salmon", lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But there's a difference between the models on sas and on r. I'll run a sample dataset and post the results from sas and r here

Comment: Here it is. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iFKuDF5UywqO4iFqo73OJ2Va7quOkd3mBzkOdWkUcAY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Julio47 you've relabeled the starting values of the bins as the midpoints.  But, if you make some minor modifications you can probably get similar results

Comment: @ nongkrong Did it. The midpoints were _actually_ midpoints on SAS. Took that in to account and it worked like a beauty. Thank you very much.